# How to connect a small PV and a wind powered motor to a rechargeable battery for educational demos?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I wish to connect a couple of small photovoltaic panels and a small motor used as energy generator to a small battery. I found these components:

[Motor](https://www.amazon.se/-/en/Small-Vertical-Turbines-Breeze-Generator/dp/B08RBTXDNW/ref=sr_1_7?keywords=elgenerator%20vind&qid=1690358741&sprefix=vind%20el%2Caps%2C230&sr=8-7):

```
Rated power: 0.55W
Output Voltage:0.01V~5.5V
Output current: 0.01mA~100mA
```

2x [solar panels](https://www.amazon.se/-/en/GTIWUNG-Micro-Energy-Science-Project/dp/B097GS2CL8/ref=pd_bxgy_img_sccl_1/259-2147243-9868526?pd_rd_w=rIs6f&content-id=amzn1.sym.2be86564-0b94-4228-b42c-351166fa8df7&pf_rd_p=2be86564-0b94-4228-b42c-351166fa8df7&pf_rd_r=GE7CWHV9PS8V8A4ZAEVH&pd_rd_wg=Rur5L&pd_rd_r=aa3030d2-e10b-4416-a631-434f24bab27c&pd_rd_i=B097GS2CL8&th=1) (in series). Specs for each panel

```
Rated power: 0.3W
Output Voltage: 3V
Output current: 100 mA (computed by myself doing 0.3W/3V)
```

[NiCD Battery](https://www.amazon.se/-/en/JINMEIXIANG-700mAh-Battery-Charger-Rechargeable/dp/B0B9B9FN7D/ref=sr_1_9?crid=33C6XFKB9SIV3&keywords=battery%204.8V%20rechargeable&qid=1690363916&sprefix=battery%204.8v%20rechargeable%2Caps%2C136&sr=8-9):

Output Voltage: 4.8V

```
   Current Not sure.   
   I should read what is written on its charger 
   but I assume it should be something around 250 mA.
```

What is the most appropriate way to connect them?

I sketched an idea but I am not sure if it will work.
Any constructive feedback is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Depends what sort of battery. Definitely not if it's Li-ion.

Comment: Ah ok, good to know. However, the battery I linked is a NiCD battery.

Comment: Later maybe. 4.8V = 4 x NiMH. Charge voltage terminate = 1.65  V/cell = 6.6V. ||3 cells better at about 4.9 - 5V. // Tst motor output at expected speed - probably makes more like 5V. || Clamping Vbat with a TL431 based regulator allows Vcharge_max to be set anywhere you want. || PV panels will happily charge to regulator voltage and don't mind shunting. They will charge 4 x NiMH. Or 3.

Comment: Thanks! Such a TL431 is a very nice component, I didn't know it. I guess you are referring to the second scheme that I sketched with your answer. My only worry with such a scheme is that the power to the battery and load is supplied only from the source that gives higher voltage after the diode, isn't it? If so, wouldn't that be a waste of energy? 
The idea of having the shunt resistor with the switch is twofold: I have read somewhere that the motor must be always connected to a load and I could also - for example -  keep the battery charge at a desired target SoC (say between 40% and 60%).

Comment: Schottky diode drops about 0.3V. PV will be OK with 3 x NimH but motor will depend critically on actual voltage generated. || You REALLY need to decide what sot of RPM it will achieve and test it. It MAY produce more V under low load and so load down OK to suit situation. PV panel is close to a constant current source so is "happy" if loaded to a lower voltage.

Comment: Thanks again. I think that at this point I should buy the components and run some tests to learn how the single components behave. Unfortunately the RPM may vary depending on the "wind". I could use a TL431 in the branch where the motor is located to limit its output voltage. It looks like there are many directions to go here... :)

Comment: @Barzi2001  The generator voltage WILL vary with wind speed. Voltage at various speed will probably matter given motor voltage ratings. What rotor do you intend to use? What diameter? What wind do you expect. || Expected power is 0.6 x V^3 x A x z || V m/s wind, A area m^2, Z = efficiency 0-1 Use 0.1 to 0.2 to start. || This facebook group should be helpful. (I'm a member). https://www.facebook.com/groups/windturbinemakers

Comment: @RussellMcMahon FYI: I made a sketch of the project and simulate it: https://tinyurl.com/249ene9y Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: @Barzi2001  The 10 Ohm resistor is not needed IF it is intended to allow the TL431 to function as a clamp. It does however reduce the TL431 clamp current to blow the 100 mA max allowed. If you want the [TL431](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Nexperia/TL431_Family.pdf) to sink more current than its max 100 mA you can use it to drive a PNP transistor or a P-Channel MOSFET. || Examples: see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/325333/3288) SEEE answer by Spehro . Or  using a MOSFET [here](https://www.radiolocman.com/shem/schematics.html?di=655923)

Answer (score 1):

This type of circuit will risk overloading your battery. NiCD is somewhat less sensitive then Li-ion, but this setup is not a good idea unless it's for a short demo. For a better solution, consider a battery charger chip like the MAX712 (see https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX712-MAX713.pdf)

Or even better, discard the NiCD batteries and use a Li-ion pack with a dedicated module such as the MH-CD42 (https://techfun.sk/en/product/charging-discharge-circuit-mh-cd42-for-batteries-with-5v-output/)

Comment: Good point! Thanks! Just for my understanding: you claimed that my scheme(s) is(are) not a good idea because the battery could reach 100% State-of-Charge (SoC) and the PV/motor could keep in pushing current into the battery? If so, what about estimating the SoC and then move the switch position on the shunt resistor depending on the current SoC (i.e. if the SoC > 90% move the switch to the shunt resistor, if SoC<35% move the switch to the battery)? Or there are other reasons by which my scheme is not good?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but if you have to do that manually then you really need to stay close and watch the circuit (which is why it's fine for a short demo), and if you want to automate the switch then measuring the actual SoC, under load, is fairly complicated. Both the chip and the module I mentioned do exactly that.

Comment: This MH-CD42 looks awesome! My intention is to design a Kalman filter for SoC estimation and to control the switch (replaced with a potentiometer in the revised scheme) to track a desired SoC and keep it (say 40%) no matter of the load. The idea of using such variable shunt resistor is due to that if the SoC reaches its target (say 40%), then I reduce the electrical power at the input of the MH-CD42 to keep 40% os SoC while feeding the load. Not sure if it make sense, anyway: new scheme: https://ibb.co/nM86mg8